# ArrayList of BufferedImage and info in HttpServletResponse

Tags: servlets, arraylist, httpresponse, bufferedimage

I have a servlet that has an ArrayList of BufferedImage and some information for every item, how may I pass them in HttpServletResponse?

I'm able to pass only one image with

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
BufferedImage buf_img = images.get(0);
ImageIO.write(buf_img, "jpg", out);
```

I need to retrieve them from an Android app, using Retrofit for info, and Picasso for the photos. 
My wish should be if I could send in httpservletResponse:

1. info as json
2. images as bufferedImage

I know maybe this is impossible, so I'm searching for another solution.

Thanks, for answering.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly, I need to retrieve the information with an Android app, not in a jsp. But I can take a look to see if there is something that can help me. 

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to edit the question to include the functional requirement. There's quite some ambiguity here. Next educated guess would be: you actually wanted to let the servlet act as a web service and return a XML or JSON response with binary content embedded? The canonical approach for that is base64-encoding binary content to text.

Comment: thanks for answering. I added requirements.
I need info issued as json, and image like bufferedImage. But if this is not possible, I would adapt to other solutions.

Comment: JSON is one big chunk of text. Basically, it's a `String`. Logically, you need to convert `BufferedImage` in a reversible way to `String`. One way is Base64 encoding. It converts bytes to characters. You can easily embed characters in a `String`. Nothing of this all has anything to do with specifically servlets and buffered images.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC.
I will try this way.

Comment: @BalusC, if I have 10 thumb images, the right way is to obtain them with a single GET, or with 10 GET?

Comment: Response depends entirely on the request of the client. If the client requests 10 images at once, then well, respond accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for all. I will try and post the solution as answer mentioned you.